# Vertical Waves: Amplitude scaling

Tags: c, unix, math

This might be more of a math question rather than a programming question, so feel free to remove if against any rules, or if an insult to anyone's intelligence.

I am generating a wave with time on the Y-axis and phase on the X-axis.

I am stuck at... the phase angle(x-axis) amplitude is not scaling with the size of the window (with unmodified newwin x-axis).

```
getmaxyx(window, y, x)                  //Get window size
xLoc = (x/2) + (cos(radiant)*(180/Pi)); //Offset to center, rad to deg
wmove(window, y, xLoc);                 //Move to xLoc location
waddch(window,ch);                      //Print char S
wrefresh(window);                       //Print buffer stored
```

I'm not too sure what and where to place the scaling factor in the xLoc equation.

*Everything is working fine (waveform/up scroll...etc) just not scaling to window width. Please help!

Thanks,
JT

Answer (score 2):

To find X-coordinate of the vertical wave point with phase `Fi` measured in radians, centered at x/2:

```
X(Fi) = x/2 * (1 + cos(Fi))   //round to int if needed
```

P.S. Use appropriate variable names like `Width` and `Height`, `W, H`  for window size to avoid confusion with coordinates

Comment: WOW... That was awfully embarrassing.
Worked perfectly!

Thanks a bunch MBo!